# Using memcpy to copy managed structures

Tags: c++-cli, memcpy

I am working in mixed mode (managed C++ and C++ in one assembly). I am in a situation something like this.

```
ManagedStructure ^ managedStructure = gcnew ManagedStructure();
//here i set different properties of managedStructure
```

then I call "Method" given below and pass it "& managedStructure"

```
Method(void *ptrToStruct)
{
    ManagedStructure ^ managedStructure2 = gcnew ManagedStructure();
    memcpy(&managedStructure2 , ptrToStruct, sizeof(managedStructure2 ));
}
```

I have following question about this scenario.

1) Is it safe to use memcpy like this? and if not what is its alternate to achieve same functionality? ( I can't change "Method" definition)

2) I am not freeing any memory as both the structures are managed. Is it fine?

Answer (score 1):

You could look into using a copy constructor or something similar.  Check out [this article](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2004/03/29/mcpp_part3.html?page=last) as it explains a few things that might be useful.
I would assume your memory model is OK since it's all managed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but you might need to pin managedStructure2 before the memcpy, look at the docs for pin_ptr<>. If it's not pinned, GC might happen on a separate thread in the middle of your memcpy, resulting in an intermittent bug.

Comment: I am having some trouble in pinning the pointer. Can u help me out here? How can I pin managedStructure2?